# Python Selenium Script generating screenshot based on remote web page url - showing some random image icon part of twitter feed / Left side bar image

Tags: python, selenium

Python Selenium Script generating screenshot based on remote web page url. Its not taking the web page visible area instead its taking a part of icon . This is happening only on the sites having twitter widget (or) the sites present / hosted in wordpress.com

used the standard selenium script to take screen shot, tools used chromedriver, Xvfb, Selenium , python and given implict wait 10 seconds as well.

Example URL : 
https://vaddicted.wordpress.com/2018/07/03/vsphere-upgrade-series-part-1-preparing-to/

And the image generated i.e. Actual output :

[image]

expected should :

[image]

After taking screenshot using selenium, i uses image magic to generate thumbnail.

```
image_name = sys.argv[1]
feed_item_url = sys.argv[2]

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

# you will not see the browser.
print "browser assigned"
browser.get(feed_item_url)
print browser.title.encode('utf-8')
time.sleep(10)
screenshot = browser.save_screenshot(image_name)
if os.path.exists(image_name):
    subprocess.call('/usr/bin/convert '+image_name+' -resize 320x240\> '+thumb_image_name+'', shell=True)
    os.unlink(image_name)
```

Comment: Try without XVFB also. Did you specify the resolution of the XVFB screen or not?

Comment: I tried with out XVFB also same issue. I killed the running process for XVFB but issue still persist.

Comment: Put a 10 second delay and try taking screenshot after she see if it is a timing issue

Comment: I already have a implict wait for 10 seconds and thread sleep 10 seconds as well. See the code snippet in the question. i have mentioned.